# Owl Carousel image slides not responding well to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web page that is using Owl Carousel for image sliders. However they are not responding well to screen resizing and I have used them before on other pages where they work fine. I have taken a video of my screen in order to demonstrate the problem: . Any help with this is really appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="module__container--half flex__responsive">
    
        <div class="module__container--item">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme filler__slider filler__slider--one">
                <div class="item filler__img--full filler__img--one"></div>
                <div class="item filler__img--full filler__img--four"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
        
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                center:true,
                autoWidth:true,
                margin:0,
                nav:true,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:1
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:3
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:5
                    }
                }
            })
            
        </script>
        
        <div class="module__container--item tablet__adjust animatedParent animateOnce" style="display: flex; display: -webkit-flex;">
            <div class="filler__content--slider" style="margin-left: 0px !important;">
                <div class="standard__content filler__content filler__content--one animated fadeInRightShort delay-375">
                    <h3 style="text-align: left;">FILLER SECTION</h3>
                    <p class="h6 standard__content--text" style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">Short introduction of the client and description of the completed project. This should be anywhere from 3-5 lines. If longer, break into sections based on client background and project overview. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet, quo modo tincidunt no, partiendo adipiscing no. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet, quo modo tincidunt no, partiendo adipiscing no. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet, quo modo tincidunt no, partiendo adipiscing no. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet, quo modo tincidunt no, partiendo adipiscing no.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.filler__slider, .filler__slider .owl-stage-outer, .filler__slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage, .filler__slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .owl-item {height: 100vw !important;}
.filler__slider .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .owl-item {width: 100vw !important;}
.filler__slider .owl-nav {display: flex !important; margin-top: -50px !important;}
.filler__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev, .filler__slider .owl-nav .owl-next {z-index: 1000 !important;}
.filler__slider .owl-nav .owl-prev {transform: rotate(180deg);}
.filler__slider .owl-nav .owl-next {transform: rotate(0deg);}
.filler__slider {overflow: hidden !important;}

.filler__slider--one .owl-nav {justify-content: flex-end !important; padding-right: 30px;}
.filler__slider--four .owl-nav {justify-content: flex-start !important; padding-left: 30px;}
.filler__content {margin: auto !important; position: relative; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 30px;}
.filler__img--full {background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: 100vw; width: 100%;}
.filler__img--one {background-image: url(images/template_filler_one.png);}
.filler__img--two {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 522px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 85vw;
}
.filler__img--three {
    width: 516px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 80vw;
}
.filler__img--four {background-image: url(images/template_filler_four.png); margin-top: 0px;}
.order__one {order: 2}
.order__two {order: 1}

.filler__content--slider {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: auto; display: flex; display: -webkit-flex;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible solution for this is to set the responsiveRefreshRate option to `responsiveRefreshRate:10` (default 200ms). However, I have now discovered a new slider plugin called Flickity, which is amazing. By far the best slider plugin I have used. [Flickity by Metafizzy](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/)